# Geth Private Network Unable to Add Light Node

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, light-clients

I have a private network setup with geth and a few machines (2 full nodes for mining and a light node). The three devices have the following IPs:

- MINER1 - 10.42.0.40
- MINER2 - 10.42.0.250
- LIGHT-NODE - 10.42.0.150

I followed the suggested setup as follows:

1. Setup account from a new directory e.g. `~/miner1`

   `geth --datadir="./" account new`
2. Create a common genesis.json block file for all participating devices (I can confirm this is the same file used on all devices)

   ```
   {
   "config": {
       "chainID"       : 10,
       "homesteadBlock": 0,
       "eip155Block":    0,
       "eip158Block":    0
   },
   "nonce": "0x01",
   "difficulty": "0x20000",
   "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
   "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "timestamp": "0x00",
   "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "extraData": "0x00",
   "gasLimit": "0x2FEFD8",
   "alloc": {
   }
   ```

   }
3. Initiate the genesis block with

   `geth --datadir="./" init genesisblock.json`
4. Startup the node

Full Node MINER1

```
geth --datadir="./" --identity "MINER1" --networkid 2008 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8501 --nodiscover --minerthreads="1" --mine --unlock 0 console
```

Full Node MINER2

```
geth --datadir="./" --identity "MINER2" --networkid 2008 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8502 --nodiscover --minerthreads="1" --mine --unlock 0 console
```

Light Node (Raspberry Pi)

```
geth --verbosity 6 --datadir="./" --cache=32 --syncmode=light --networkid 2008 --rpc --rpccorsdomain 0.0.0.0 --rpcport="8503" --nodiscover --unlock 0 console
```

5. Perform manual discovery using `admin.addPeer("enodeURL")`

Run from MINER1 to add MINER2

```
admin.addPeer("enode://a90cdb6f0c48b60052fc995fb3a2ae45de28baec009ba526418d46ff0a1e9005f6a79883f6b821b964accdadc5017481409e8494e5ad39f22453c3ecff3b8228@10.42.0.250:30303")
```

This works perfectly and can be seen using `admin.peers` that the two miner nodes are able to synchronize

6. Perform the same manual discovery on the light node to add MINER1 and MINER2

`admin.addPeer("enode://a902f3231e561546896f4619bb7129e67f3b46ee4bc6a86e35ca1f575444e9f25dcb65bf0e09b02fd2714ce59bbb496a7783486d39eca4a17327ae1bacb3c699@10.42.0.40:30303")`

`admin.addPeer("enode://a90cdb6f0c48b60052fc995fb3a2ae45de28baec009ba526418d46ff0a1e9005f6a79883f6b821b964accdadc5017481409e8494e5ad39f22453c3ecff3b8228@10.42.0.250:30303")`

This results in a `true` response from the console but waiting and running `admin.peers` returns no peers - `[]`

Using the `--verbosity 6` command line argument I receive the following information after running the `admin.addPeer("enodeURL")` command:

```
DEBUG[02-10|16:30:21] Adding static node                       node=enode://a902f3231e561546896f4619bb7129e67f3b46ee4bc6a86e35ca1f575444e9f25dcb65bf0e09b02fd2714ce59bbb496a7783486d39eca4a17327ae1bacb3c699@10.42.0.40:30303
TRACE[02-10|16:30:21] New dial task                            task="staticdial a902f3231e561546 10.42.0.40:30303"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:21] Rejected peer                            id=a902f3231e561546 addr=10.42.0.40:30303 conn=staticdial err="useless peer"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:21] Dial task done                           task="staticdial a902f3231e561546 10.42.0.40:30303"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:21] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (29.999612993s)"
DEBUG[02-10|16:30:40] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
TRACE[02-10|16:30:51] Dial task done                           task="wait for dial hist expire (29.999612993s)"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:52] New dial task                            task="staticdial a902f3231e561546 10.42.0.40:30303"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:52] Rejected peer                            id=a902f3231e561546 addr=10.42.0.40:30303 conn=staticdial err="useless peer"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:52] Dial task done                           task="staticdial a902f3231e561546 10.42.0.40:30303"
TRACE[02-10|16:30:52] New dial task                            task="wait for dial hist expire (29.999654995s)"
DEBUG[02-10|16:31:00] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[02-10|16:31:20] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
```

As you can see I get a Rejected peer with `err="useless peer"` in the trace.

Running `net.listening`returns `true` and I am able to ping the MINER1 and MINER2 hosts from the light node.

Upon running the geth commands I am warned about no UPNP enabled on the network:

```
DEBUG[02-10|16:28:42] Couldn't add port mapping                proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPnP or NAT-PMP" err="no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered"
```

but this shouldn't affect the private network on the LAN when I do not plan on my network communicating over the internet/WAN should it?

Is anyone able to shed any light on why I am unable to attach my light node to the full nodes on my private network?

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First a create the any location this genesisblock file saved : `/genesisblock.json`

```
{
    "nonce"     : "0x0000000000000055",
    "mixHash"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "0x20000",
    "gasLimit"  : "0x800000",
    "timestamp" : "0x0",
    "extraData" : "",
    "coinbase"  : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc"     : {},
    "config"    : {
        "chainId": 100,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    }
}
```

Then Initiate the genesis file this commend run:

```
geth --datadir "D:\bolckchain\chaindata" init "c\genesisblock.json"
```

Then Private network create : this code run :

```
geth --networkid 13 --port 30303 --datadir "D:\bolckchain\chaindata" console
```

Private network create then mist or walled open

Then anther node add the private network this private network is `13`

Then anther node add this network then addPeer : Example :

```
 admin.addPeer("enode://a902f3231e561546896f4619bb7129e67f3b46ee4bc6a86e35ca1f575444e9f25dcb65bf0e09b02fd2714ce59bbb496a7783486d39eca4a17327ae1bacb3c699@10.42.0.40:30303")
```

IP configuration (enode creation with ip address)
    IP-192.168.1.114

10.42.0.40 this miens anther computer ip: example 192.168.0.101

Then peer check this commend run :

```
$ admin
```

New Account crate commend :

```
->personal.newAccount()
```

Then password provided and re-password then new account create .

and all account list this commend :

```
 ->personal.listAccounts
```

and miner ether add this commend run :

```
-> miner.start(1)
```

sometime wait and account ether add:

and miner stop commend :

```
 -> miner.stop()
```

and block number information this commend :

```
-> eth.getBlock(10)
```

10 miens 10 number block .

Remove Peer command :

```
-> admin.removePeer()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alomgir Hossen but my question is related to trouble adding the light node to my network. The full nodes recognise each other without issue but I am unable to get the light node to sync with them

Comment: oh yes this link help link try it https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/what-is-geths-light-sync-and-why-is-it-so-fast

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the light client is still in development and by default a node will not connect to light peers.

Set this parameter start of geth :

```
--lightserv value                 Maximum percentage of time allowed for serving LES requests (0-90) (default: 0)
```

For example :

```
geth --lightserv 20
```

For more details, sees the official documentation [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), or this question [How to run a "server" for light clients?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11014/how-to-run-a-server-for-light-clients)